# Conditional execution of a method using Aspects in Spring AOP

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am new to Spring AOP. I need to execute methods only if the user is authorized.
Here's my code.

```
@Before("some pointcut")
public HttpStatus checkUserAuthentication(String userName)
{
   if( userAuthorized(userName) )
   {
       //go on executing method
   } else {
      return HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN; 
   } 
}
```

Is there any alternative for ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed when using JoinPoint or can I use ProceedingJoinPoint with @Before advice? How to proceed with executing the if statement if the user is authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using @Around advice. and changing the return type to Object so that it can return ProceedingJoinPoint on successfull verification.

```
@Around("some pointcut")
public Object checkUserAuthentication(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String userName)
{
   if( userAuthorized(userName) )
   {
       return pjp.roceed();
   } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN); 
   } 
}
```

using @Around as advice the control can be passed to the method after verification.